# Shared memory dictionary creation too slow using multiprocessing.Manager()

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, multiprocessing, xlrd

I have a code in which I need to read an excel file and store the information into dictionaries.

I have to use `multiprocessing.Manager()` to create the dictionaries in order to be able to retrieve calculation output from a function that I run using `multiprocess.Process`.

The problem is that, when `multiprocessing.Manager()` and `manager.dict()` is used to create a dictionary it takes ~400 times longer than using only `dict()` (and `dict()` is not a shared memory structure).

Here is a sample code to verify the diference:

```
import xlrd
import multiprocessing
import time

def DictManager(inp1, inp2):
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    Dict = manager.dict()
    Dict['input1'] = inp1
    Dict['input2'] = inp2
    Dict['Output1'] = None
    Dict['Output2'] = None
    return Dict

def DictNoManager(inp1, inp2):
    Dict = dict()
    Dict['input1'] = inp1
    Dict['input2'] = inp2
    Dict['Output1'] = None
    Dict['Output2'] = None
    return Dict

def ReadFileManager(excelfile):
    DictList = []
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(excelfile)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    line = 2
    for line in range(2,sheet.nrows):
        inp1 = sheet.cell(line,2).value
        inp2 = sheet.cell(line,3).value
        dictionary = DictManager(inp1, inp2)
        DictList.append(dictionary)
    print 'Done!'

def ReadFileNoManager(excelfile):
    DictList = []
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(excelfile)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    line = 2
    for line in range(2,sheet.nrows):
        inp1 = sheet.cell(line,2).value
        inp2 = sheet.cell(line,3).value
        dictionary = DictNoManager(inp1, inp2)
        DictList.append(dictionary)
    print 'Done!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    excelfile = 'MyFile.xlsx'

    start = time.time()
    ReadFileNoManager(excelfile)
    end = time.time()
    print 'Run time NoManager:', end - start, 's'

    start = time.time()
    ReadFileManager(excelfile)
    end = time.time()
    print 'Run time Manager:', end - start, 's'
```

Is there a way to improve the performance of `multiprocessing.Manager()`?

If the answer is No, is there any other shared memory structure that I can use to replace what I am doing and improve performance?

I would appreciate your help!

EDIT:

My main function uses the following code:

```
def MyFunction(Dictionary, otherdata):
    #Perform calculation and save results in the dictionary
    Dict['Output1'] = Value1
    Dict['Output2'] = Value2

ListOfProcesses = []
for Dict in DictList:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=MyFunction, args=(Dict, otherdata)
    p.start()
    ListOfProcesses.append(p)  
for p in ListOfProcesses:
    p.join()
```

If I do not use the manager, I will not be able to retrieve the Outputs.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to use the extra process for? Are you going to be reading multiple excel files at once?

Comment: Why don't you use threads?

Comment: Threads are mainly useful when there are I/O restraints like http calls. Multiprocessing is better for cpu heavy tasks

Comment: No, I read only one excel file. Then, I use the data of each line to create a dictionary and for each dictionary I run a function to perform some calculation and save the results in the dictionary fields. This last step is what I calculate in parallel.

Comment: In that case, I would read in the excel file without the manager

Comment: Then use a Pool to run your function on all dicts that you have, no need for a manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I recommend using the main process to read in the excel file. Then using multiprocessing for the function calls. Just add your function to `apply_function` and make sure it returns whatever you want. `results` will contain a list of your results.

Update: I changed map to starmap to include your extra argument

```
def ReadFileNoManager(excelfile):
    DictList = []
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(excelfile)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    line = 2
    for line in range(2,sheet.nrows):
        inp1 = sheet.cell(line,2).value
        inp2 = sheet.cell(line,3).value
        dictionary = DictNoManager(inp1, inp2)
        DictList.append(dictionary)
    print 'Done!'
    return DictList

def apply_function(your_dict, otherdata):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    excelfile = 'MyFile.xlsx'
    dict_list = ReadFileNoManager(excelfile)    
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    results = pool.starmap(apply_function, zip(dict_list, repeat(otherdata)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am getting an error: "KeyError: 'input'" in the map method now..

Comment: Ok. I was able to run the code, but the problem is that `apply_function` should be able to edit the dictionary. I tried to do `your_dict['Output1'] = 'It Worked'` in the apply_function and when I print the dictionaries in the main function I get  `your_dict['Output1'] = None` .What happens is that the Pool function creates a copy of the dictionary because it is not memory shared.. That is why I needed the manager in the first place.

Comment: why cant you use the dictionaries in `results`?

Comment: That is right! Sorry, I havent noticed that with `pool.map` I could get the returned object of apply_function. That should work on my actual code! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!